# How do you use a Matrix to toggle between multiple fields from multiple blocks?

Tags: matrix, switch

I have 1 Matrix field:
contentBlock

With 2 Block types:
text
photo

With nested fields:
text -> text
photo -> photo

My attempt at using if statements, which didn't work, to toggle between text and photo looks like the following:

```
{% for block in entry.contentBlock %}
    {% if block.type == 'text' %}
        {{ block.text }}
    {% endif %}
    {% elseif block.type == 'image' %}
        {% set image = block.image.first() %}
            {% if image %}
                <img src="{{ image.getUrl('thumb') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
            {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Would using {% switch %} be a better method, or was I close to correct using the if statements?
I think getting the hang of this will open up the true posibilities of using Craft Matrix fields.

Thank you for any input on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using switch is a good way to handle this, but it looks like your conditionals are just a little off:

```
{% for block in entry.contentBlock %}
    {% if block.type == 'text' %}
        {{ block.text }}
    {% elseif block.type == 'photo' %}
        {% set photo = block.photo.first() %}
        {% if photo %}
            <img src="{{ photo.getUrl('thumb') }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}">
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The same thing with the switch syntax would be:

```
{% for block in entry.contentBlock %}

    {% switch block.type %}
        {% case "text" %}
            {{ block.text }}
        {% case "photo" %}
            {% set photo = block.photo.first() %}
            {% if photo %}
                <img src="{{ photo.getUrl('thumb') }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}">
            {% endif %}
    {% endswitch %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried both of these methods and was not able to get the image/s to show using either; the text does show and seems to be the only part working. I tried amending the code for image.gerUrl to remove thumb, in case that that the issue, but that didn't work. Do I need to make further reference to where the image is located, or use a for entry in statement? Is these something missing which is assumed the user would have already included?

Comment: Is your second block named `photo` rather than `image`? If so try `case "photo"` for the second switch case. If the field in that block type is also named `photo` and not `image`, you'll need to update `block.image` to be `block.photo`.

Comment: The solution was to rename image to photo in both instances you mentioned. Thank you for helping.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the code in my answer to use `photo` instead of `image`.